# Next.js - no data in component when navigating from other route

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm new to next.js. 
I'm rendering my page view on the backend side:

```
module.exports = (server, app) => {
  server.get('/setup', (req, res) => {
    const testData = {
      name: "Test",
      testProp: "testVal",
    };

    return app.render(req, res, '/setup', testData);
  });
};
```

When I'm refreshing the page on my `/setup` route in the browser I can see the data inside getInitialProps, this is fine. But when I'm navigating from the other route to `/setup` route I can't see the data. Why this is happening and how can I change it in order to see the data? Here's my page code:

```
import { withAuth } from '../utils/withAuth';

const Setup = props => {
  console.log(props); // when linking there is no expected data here
  return(
    <div>Setup here</div>
  )
};

Setup.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
  return { ...ctx.query };
};

export default withAuth(Setup);
```

Comment: You are only passing the data if the route is '/setup'.

Comment: But I'm navigating from the other route to /setup route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When navigating from other routes, you are not rendering server-side, so you have to fetch the data from the server in getInitialProps.

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

const Setup = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return(
     <div>Setup here</div>
  )
}

Setup.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  if (ctx.req) {
   // server-side
   return { ...ctx.query }
  } else {
   // client-side
   const res = await fetch('API/setup')
   const json = await res.json()
   return { ...json }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have related question, the answer you could know. When I'm rendering the the `/setup` as above I cannot see my current cookie in `req.cookies`. When I'm doing a standard fetching like in axios I'm using withCredentials set to true. But I cannot see it when this is rendered by the server.

Comment: It would be good to see the code, because it's not so much info that you provided.

Maybe you should check out this repo: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-cookie-auth
Probably you can get an answer from there.